# Where does php code go when uploading files

Tags: php, html

I am following a step by step guide on W3schools website on how to upload a file. The only thing I don't understand is where does the php code go because if I try to put them below the html then I get notices stating "file" is undefined.

Does anyone know where the php code goes? If somebody could provide a sample of the layout of the code from W3schools then it would be very helpful. I want to see what it all is supposed to look like but I keep getting notices.

Click [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp) to view the file upload steps on the W3schools website.

Thank you

Comment: I think you need to give us more details about what you trying to do...

Comment: Im just follow all the steps on the file upload section in the w3schools website. I want to be able to upload a file from my page, the html works fine but if you go further down in the website you get php code on file restrictions uploading script and saving uploaded files. I first tried uploading script php code and put it below my html but it gives me notices saying "file" is undefined, I havn't changed any code, I just used the code on the website

Comment: Start here: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php

Comment: @MalcolmPickup are you using a .php page?  you can't have php on html unless your web server is setup to parse php code from an html file.

Comment: My page is a php page not a html page it is a php file.

Comment: [w3fools.com](http://w3fools.com). Really, I recommend that you try to avoid w3Schools as much as possible, as they're not as much of a reliable source as others. In fact, their PHP tutorials do nothing about the [SQL Injection vulnerabilities](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp) (and come on, Quagmire is 65!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// checking if the user has sent the data to the form
if (isset($_POST['upload_file']))
{
  // checking if the file size doesn't exceed the maximum size
  if ($_FILES['upload_file']['size'] < 10485760)
  {
    // checking if the user selected a file or thera are errors
    if ($_FILES['upload_file']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK)
    {
      // checking if the file type is allowed or not
      if ($_FILES['upload_file']['type'] == 'image/jpeg' || $_FILES['upload_file']['type'] == 'image/gif' || $_FILES['upload_file']['type'] == 'image/png')
      {
        $file_name = date("Hisu");

        if ($_FILES['upload_file']['type']=='image/jpeg')
          $file_name    = $file_name.".jpg";
        if ($_FILES['new_picture']['type']=='image/gif')
          $file_name    = $file_name.".gif";
        if ($_FILES['new_picture']['type']=='image/png')
          $file_name    = $file_name.".png";

        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload_file']['tmp_name'], 'objects/upload/files/'.$file_name);

        $URL_file   = 'objects/upload/files/'.$file_name;

        mysql_query("INSERT INTO uploads (URL) VALUES (".$URL_file.")"); 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a php parser to view any php page.

Your HTML page has a form, I presume, which loosely resembles the following:

```
<form action="handler.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="my_file" />
</form>
```

You need to make a new page called "handler.php" with the following:

```
<?php
    //the file is stored in the server's temporary files folder. The file will live there for as long as the page is loaded for, which is on average... less than 1 second.

    //You need to execute all your commands before the end of the page. otherwise the file will be gone!
    //To do that, use this:
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], "address")
    //where you replace "address" with the location you want on the server.
?>
```

Remember, you need a PHP parser to execute the PHP page.

Answer (score 0):

The php code goes into its own file "upload_file.php", and you host it on a PHP-enabled webserver.

Answer (score 0):

First you must specify the enctype attribute in the form tag.

```
<form action="demo_post_enctype.asp" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Then you can write the PHP code in the same document or in a new file. If you put PHP code into the same document you have to use action="?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" because informations will be delivered to the server.

I suggest you to write the PHP code on the top of the same document.

Comment: So If I have a php page (create_session.php) and in that page is a form wihch action is to post details to another page (QandAfile.php), then if include the enctype tag in my form and my file upload input is in that form, can I then place the php code on the same document (create_session.php) or do I put the PHP code in the QandAfile.php file?

Comment: Wait, when you submit the form where do you send informations? To PHP_SELF or another page? By the way, if I understand you right, you can.

Comment: When I submit the page, all the details go to the QandAfile.php page, my form tag looks like this at moment: <form action="QandAFileTable.php" method="post" id="sessionForm">

Comment: enctype="multipart/form-data"
add this in form, it's indispensable to upload a file. What did you want to know? Where place PHP code?

Comment: Yes do I place the php code on the same page where the from is (create_session.php) or the same page where the form details will be posted  (QandAFile.php)?

Comment: Where you want. If you wrote action="QandAFile.php" then you must post PHP code there, else you can post in the same document. The PHP code must be where you specific in action attribute. If you want to process data in the same page you can write action="?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>, else you can, as you did, define a page that will process your data.

Comment: So just to clarify copy and paste the php code for creating an upload scripts, restricting uploads and saving uploaded files into the QandAfile.php because thats where the form details are going to be posted to.

Comment: I'll write you in a new answer

Comment: Thanks I will mark your answer as well. Thank You for your help :)